# Rserve hangs when oppening multiple connections

Tags: java, r, rserve

I start Rserve:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0\bin\x64> "C:\Users\XXXX\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\3.5\Rserve\libs\x64\Rserve.exe" --RS-port 1000
```

Run the following java code:

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;

public class TestR {
    private  RConnection con;
    private  RConnection con2;
    public TestR(){
        try {
            con = new RConnection();
            con2 = new RConnection();
        } catch (RserveException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Double test(){
        try {

            double d = con.eval("1+1").asDouble();
            double c = con2.eval("1+1").asDouble();
            return d+c;
        } catch (RserveException | REXPMismatchException e) {
            return (double)(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I created the following class on JUnit to test it:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestRTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        TestR t = new TestR();
        t.test();
    }

}
```

When I run this test, it stops while instaciating the connections, it creates the first one, but does hangs on the second. Any idea why this could be happening?

[image: First, no connections established]

ok

[image: Second, one connection established]

ok

[image: Hangs on second connection]

hangs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue might be related to a problem with Multithreading.

Unix: no problem, one Rserve instance can serve mulitple calls.

Windows: Rserve can't create a seperate process by forking the current process.
--> create a new Rserve process for each thread (listening on a different port), a new Rserve connection on the corresponding port has to be established as well.

`RConnection connection = new RConnection(HOST, PORT);`

If you need more input, do not hesitate to ask. I can also provide my full class code for creating several R instances with Rserve if you want to.

See this [Java class](https://github.com/matthiassommer/forecast-r-java/blob/master/src/forecasting/RServeConnection.java) I used to run several instances of R with Rserve.

Comment: Tnx! this works, will just have to control new workers to use this connections...